# Как в laravel validator вывести для 1-го поля и для одного и того же правила 2 разные ошибки?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, laravel5.4

Есть поле email при регистрации и при авторизации,

но для регистрации по правилу required я хочу вывести

Поле E-mail обязательное при регистрации, а при авторизации

Поле E-mail обязательное при авторизации

это все нужно брать из файла validation

Как для двух разных случаев с одинаковым названием полей брать разные сообщения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не указали как именно вы вылидируете, но можете посмотреть по аналогии для своего случая.

В Laravel можно для валидатора задавать свои сообщения об ошибках, к примеру:

```
$messages = [
    'email.required' => 'Поле E-mail обязательное при регистрации',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

Аналогично задаете массив для валидатора при авторизации, этого достаточно.

Более детально почитайте в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#custom-error-messages).

Comment: а можно как-то переписать 
$messages = [
    'email.required' => 'Поле E-mail обязательное при регистрации',
]; на 
$messages = [
   'comment' => ['required' => 'Поле E-mail обязательное при регистрации'],
  ];

Comment: Нет, там через точку всё идёт.

Comment: можно массив в array_dot () обернуть

Comment: Я дал решение, а там уже извращаться можете как угодно)